# Is there any way to write "null" value from database to csv file?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, bufferedwriter

My first question is - Is BufferedWriter capable of writing null value to a file?
In my case, I am trying to export every data from database to csv file. There are null values in the database. I can export database without null values by using BufferedWriter. But not working with null. My question is , is it possible to export database including null with my current code? Here is the code.

This is export class-

```
    private fun export() {
    try {
        db=DataBaseHelper(this)
        val db=this.openOrCreateDatabase(REAL_DATABASE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null)
        val selectQuery=
            "Select T.date,T.location, M.barcode,M.onhand_qty,T.scanned_qty,(M.onhand_qty-T.scanned_qty) as 'DIFFERENCE' from Master M Left Outer Join transaction_table T  On M.barcode = T.barcode1  "
        val cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
        var rowcount: Int=0
        var colcount: Int=0

                val saveFile="/sdcard/Download/original.csv"
                val fw=FileWriter(saveFile)

                val bw=BufferedWriter(fw)
                rowcount=cursor.getCount()
                colcount=cursor.getColumnCount()

                if (rowcount>0) {
                    cursor!!.moveToFirst()

                    for (i in 0 until colcount) {
                        if (i != colcount - 1) {

                            bw.write(cursor!!.getColumnName(i) + ",")

                        } else {

                            bw.write(cursor!!.getColumnName(i))
                        }
                    }
                    bw.newLine()

                    for (i in 0 until rowcount) {
                        cursor!!.moveToPosition(i)

                        for (j in 0 until colcount) {
                            if (j != colcount - 1)
                                bw.write(cursor!!.getString(j) + ",")
                            else
                                bw.write(cursor!!.getString(j))//This is where I get the error message
                        }
                        bw.newLine()
                    }
                    bw.flush()
                }

    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()

    } finally {

    }

}
```

This is the error message-

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Can you not just check for null and deal accordingly with that? e.g. an empty string, the string "null"?

Comment: How should I check and deal ? Can you provide some references?

Comment: It would depend on how you are going to use the data in the rest of your project. What would be better for your use case? "" or "null" ?

Comment: In my case it would better to check "null".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this

```
val s = cursor!!.getString(j)
    if(s == null)
        bw.write("whatever string value you want here")
    else
        bw.write(s)
```

Comment: That's what I really wanted. Right on the spot. Thanks :)